# My code won't add all the inputted costs together including the tax to create the total

Tags: python

Individual costs are according to the users input, however my code won't add them to create the total cost][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iQEr.png)
When it runs it keeps the variable totalcost the same.

It should calculate the total cost based on the formulas in my functions.  I can't figure out why this won't work.

```
    import sys*
#VARIABLES
total_EntrancePrice=0
costcoins=0
totalcost=0

#PEOPLE IN PARTY
print("How many people are included in your party?")
num_of_people= int(input())

#ENTRANCE FEE
entrance_fee_price = 10
def get_total_EntrancePrice():
  total_EntrancePrice=num_of_people*entrance_fee_price
  print("Your total price with %s people is %s dollars" %(num_of_people, total_EntrancePrice))
get_total_EntrancePrice() 

yes = "yes"
yes1 = "Yes"
no = "no"
no1 = "No"

#COINS?
coins = str(input("Would you like to buy coins?:"))
if coins == yes or yes1:
  print("Okay great! Each coin costs 20 cents. How many coins would you like?")
  coinsbought=int(input())
  priceforcoin=.20
  def get_costcoins():
    costcoins=coinsbought*priceforcoin
    print("Your total price of %s coins is %s dollars" %(coinsbought, costcoins))
  get_costcoins()
elif coins ==no or no1:
  print("No worries, it's not mandatory to buy some")
else:
  print("Im sorry, I dont understand your response")
#TOTAL COST WITH TAX
tax=total_EntrancePrice+costcoins/10
def get_totalcost():
  totalcost=total_EntrancePrice+costcoins+tax
  print("Your total for today with %s people and %s coins is %s dollars. Thank you for visitiing our Lost at Sea location. Have a wonderful day!" %(num_of_people, coinsbought,totalcost))
get_totalcost()
```

Comment: Can you post the *text* of your code, and not just a screenshot?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of **scope**, which can be confusing if this is your first time coming across it. I am no experienced coder myself, so please forgive any technical inaccuracies. I will try to explain the jist of the problem.
So, take a simple example:

```
var = 1
def change():
    var = 2
change()
print(var)
```

prints 1

The reason for this strange behaviour, is that when var is changed in `change`, it is restricted to inside the function.
When you print `var`, you are printing it outside the function, or outside the scope of the new variable. Had you done this:

```
var = 1
def change():
    var = 2
    print(var)
change()
```

the output would be `2`, but `var`, from outside the function, would still be 1.

There are multiple ways to solve your problem. One is using (nasty) global variables. Another is to set the variable to the output of a function IN THE 'OUTSIDE' SCOPE with `return`. Here's what I mean.

```
var = 1
def change():
    return 2

var = change()
print(var)
```

prints 2

Returning, in case you have not come across it, is the function returning an output. when I say `var = change()`, python does something like: "so, `var` is going to be equal to this thing `change`, and when I run change I get this output `2`, so therefore `var = 2`.
In your case you would calculate the cost in your function, then return it and assign this output to a variable outside the function.

Try and implement this in your own code!